# Windows Admin Center Login issue

Tags: windows, windows-admin-center

I installed the WAC on a server to act as gateway server.

But when I try to now connect to the gateway server or any other server, I am not able to connect and getting below message :

> "The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the
> request.
> Verify that the service on the destination is running and is
> accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
> WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
> WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
> command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service:
> "winrm quickconfig".

WinRM setting are proper on the server , but its still not authenticating me even though my account have admin access to the gateway and aother servers .

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you check the WinRM logs to see if you can find interesting informations ? `Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Remote Management`

Comment: I am getting 3 errors :
Event 161 : "The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig""

Comment: Event 49 : "The WinRM protocol operation failed due to the following error: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig"."

Comment: Event 142 : "WSMan operation Enumeration failed, error code 2150858770"